# Using Javascript to trim and send to clipboard

Tags: javascript, copy, trim

I've got the below Javascript that copies the contents of a div to clipboard.

The contents of the div always vary, however the results currently always have about 5 blank lines, each consisting of a blank space before the results. I can't change this so I want the below function to trim all the white space before and after the results.

I'm aware that

```
str.trim()
```

Is probably the best, however being a javascript novice, I've been struggling to insert it into the below.

```
<script>
function copyToClipboard(element) {
var $temp = $("<textarea>");
var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
$("body").append($temp);
$temp.val(    $(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n").replace(/<\/?[a-zA-Z]+\/?>/g, '')).select();

document.execCommand("copy");
$temp.remove();
}
```

Is anyone able to help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet works perfectly for me. However, if you were to insert trim somewhere, it'd be here:

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<textarea>");
    var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n").replace(/<\/?[a-zA-Z]+\/?>/g, '').trim()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

The explanation is that $(element).html() is a string, and is **the string** you want to trim after you replace the things you want to replace.

Full code snippet for html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Copy</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="copy" contenteditable="true">HI<br />I am me! <span>I want to kill you!</span></div>
        <button class="copy-button">copy</button>
        <script>

            function copyToClipboard(element) {
            var $temp = $("<textarea>");
            var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
                $("body").append($temp);
                $temp.val($(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n").replace(/<\/?[a-zA-Z]+\/?>/g, '').trim()).select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                $temp.remove();
            }
            $('.copy-button').on('click', _ => {
                copyToClipboard($('.copy'));
                console.log("HI");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```